# Creating a dropdown menu when hovering over button which is not a parent

Tags: php, html, css

So i'm trying to create a navigation bar with a button which opens a dropdown menu by hovering over it.
The problem is, that the div tag of the button isn't the parent of the dropdown menu so i cant set the position of the menu relative.
So how would this be possible?

MainPage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="MainPage/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Titel der Webseite</title>

    <div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" type="button" href="MainPage.php">Home</a>

      <?php
        if(isset($_GET["removeCookie"])) {
          unset($_COOKIE["session"]);
        }
        if(!isset($_COOKIE["session"])) {
          include_once 'notLoggedIn.php';
        } else {
          include_once 'loggedin.php';
        }
       ?>
    </div>
    <div1 class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="MainPage.php?removeCookie">Loggout</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div1>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

loggedin.php:

```
<?php?>
<link href="MainPage/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

   <a type="button" class="dropbtn">
     <?php
     require_once 'MYSQL/mysql.php';
     $sql = "SELECT username FROM userinfo WHERE sessionID = ?;";
     $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysql);
     if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
       header("location: Login.php?error=SQLError");
       exit();
     }
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_COOKIE["session"]);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
     if($result->num_rows > 0) {
       $username;
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $username = $row["username"];
       }
     }
    echo $username;
    ?>
   </a>
```

css of main and loggedin.php:

```
body {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.topnav {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #404040;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-self: center;
}

.topnav a.login {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.register {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 8%;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: black;
}
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.topnav a.dropbtn {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.topnav a.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding classes and functions to your HTML elements and a JS file it works. If you have more questions or an other problem just write a comment :)

```js
// ADDED SIMPLE JS
dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

function showdropdown() {
    dropdown.style.display = 'block';
}
function hidedropdown() {
    dropdown.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.topnav {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #404040;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-self: center;
}

.topnav a.login {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.register {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 8%;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: black;
}
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.topnav a.dropbtn {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.topnav a.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="MainPage/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Titel der Webseite</title>

    <div class="topnav">
     <!-- ADD MOUSEOVER AND MOUSE OUT FUNCTIONS -->
      <a onmouseover="showdropdown()" onmouseout="hidedropdown()" class="active" type="button" href="MainPage.php">Home</a>

      <?php
        if(isset($_GET["removeCookie"])) {
          unset($_COOKIE["session"]);
        }
        if(!isset($_COOKIE["session"])) {
          include_once 'notLoggedIn.php';
        } else {
          include_once 'loggedin.php';
        }
       ?>
    </div>
    <!-- ADD THE DROPDOWN ID -->
    <div1 id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="MainPage.php?removeCookie">Loggout</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div1>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```